# Fetching for each element within array in MongoDb

Tags: json, database, mongodb

I have an 'users' collection. I store id's of users I follow in 'following' field.

```
{
     "_id": {
     "$oid": "5eab360253ec352e3cc791d6"
     },
     "email": "koray@gmail.com",
     "password": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
     "following": ["5ea8879dfc286e1154a866cb", "5ea8879dfc286e1154a866c"],
     "posts": [{
        "head": "deneme header",
        "body": "deneme body",
        "is_private": false
    }]
}
```

I want to get posts of users I follow as well as posts belogs to me but can't manage to pull it off.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `db.collection.find({ $or: [ {  _id: "5ea8879dfc286e1154a866cb"  }, { "following": "5ea8879dfc286e1154a866cb"  }  ] })` ?

Comment: yes but this gives me just one following's posts. I need every following id's posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) and fetch documents from the same collection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: "5eab360253ec352e3cc791d6" } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection",
            let: { following_users: "$following" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$_id", "$$following_users" ] } } },
                { $project: { posts: 1 } }
            ],
            as: "following_posts"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uvmDaHQpDJT)